# Thread-safe weak-keys hash map

Tags: scala, caching, concurrency, scala-collections

How doe I get a concurrent or thread-safe `Map` in Scala whose keys are weak? For example, there is `collection.mutable.WeakHashMap` but it doesn't seem to support concurrent access/update. A cheap solution would be to hide it behind a regular Java synchronized lock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Guava's [MapMaker](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html).

An example from the doc shows exactly what you need (translated into Scala):

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap

val timers: ConcurrentMap[Request, Stopwatch] = 
    new MapMaker().concurrencyLevel(4).weakKeys.makeMap
```

This is, of course, Java map, but you can easily wrap it into Scala map:

```
import java.{util => ju}
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import scala.collection.mutable

val javaMap: ju.Map[String,String] = ...
val scalaMap: mutable.Map[String,String] = javaMap.asScala
```

Comment: Ok, but is there something less heavy-weight than drawing in a complete third-party library?

Comment: @0__ If you want a map that is both _concurrent_ (not just synchronized) and has weak keys then I don't think such implementation exists in standard libraries.